# Recursion functions - Output is incorrect

Tags: c++, recursion

I am creating a program that uses recursion functions to count the vowels in a sentence and to determine if it is a palindrome. The problem I am getting is that it says the sentence entered is not palindrome even if it is.. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

struct Sentence
{
    int CountVowels(string , int);

    public:
    Sentence (string);
    bool isPal(string , int);
    void Print();
    string s;
    int numVowel;
    int length;
    //~Sentence();

};

Sentence :: Sentence (string b)
{
    s = b;
    length = 0;
    numVowel = CountVowels(s, 0);
}

int Sentence :: CountVowels(string myWord, int startindex)
{
    length ++;
    int pandi; 

    if(myWord[startindex])
    {
        if (myWord[startindex] != 'a' && myWord[startindex] != 'e' && myWord[startindex] != 'i' && myWord[startindex] != 'o' && myWord[startindex] != 'u')
        {
            pandi = 0;
        }
    else pandi = 1;
    return pandi + CountVowels(myWord, startindex + 1);
    } 
    return 0;
}

bool Sentence :: isPal(string myWord, int size)
{
    int r = myWord.size() - size;
    int t = size - 1;


    if (size == r || r == t)

        return true;


    if ((myWord[r]) != (myWord[t]))

        return false;


    return isPal(myWord, -- size);
}

void Sentence :: Print()
{
    cout << s [-- length];
    if (length == 0)
    {
        cout << endl;
        return;

    }
    Print ();
}

/*Sentence :: ~Sentence()
{
    cout << "\ntilde delete\n\n";
}*/

int main ()
{
    string userW;

    cout << "Enter a sentence: \n";
    getline(cin, userW);
    userW.erase(remove_if(userW.begin(), userW.end(), [](char c) {return !isalpha(c); }), userW.end());
    Sentence userSent(userW);

    cout << "The number of vowels in the sentence is " << userSent.numVowel << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "The sentence " << userSent.s << " is" << 
    (userSent.isPal(userSent.s, userSent.s.size()) ? " Palindrome\n" : " Not Palindrome\n");


    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:
I am now trying to remove special characters. So it looks like this

```
string userW;

        cout << "Enter a sentence: \n";
        getline(cin, userW);
        userW.erase(remove_if(userW.begin(), userW.end(), [](char c) {return !isalpha(c); }), userW.end());
```

But I am getting this error:

```
In function 'int main()':
88:85: error: 'remove_if' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Are you sure its not working? what example u tried?

Comment: well I used the word desserts which backwards is stressed and it says its not a palindrome...

Comment: the issue u r having is that u r only returning true for palindrome if the all the words are palindrome itself...

Comment: the word desserts is not a palindrome, right?

Comment: This is what the assignment says: Write a bool function that uses recursion to determine if a string argument is a palindrome. The function should return true if the argument reads the same forward and backward. Demonstrate the function in a program. A palindrome is any word, phrase, or sentence that reads the same forward and backward. Here are some well-known palindromes:

Able was I, ere I saw Elba -- 

A man, a plan, a canal, Panama -- 

Desserts, I stressed --

Kayak

Comment: Works like a charm if you enter "desserts I stressed". You must remove the comma and use lowercase (or, anywas, same case) letters. But otherwise it works. It also works with "AblE was I ere I saw ElbA" and "amanaplanacanalpanama", without spaces.

Comment: I confirm it works, but by ignoring any special chcracters, spaces or commas. From the examples of the assignments, it is required to remove special characters before checking for Palindrome.

Comment: this is an obvious error. Print returns void, just call it, dont send it to cout.

Comment: Your original question wasn't really a programming question. Based on comments, it seems you misunderstood palindromes. But your edits are now making your question a moving target.

Comment: I got it thank you all so much !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+palindrome

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine except that it does not remove commas, spaces and anything that is not alphabetic from the sentence. Also, you need to do a case-insensitive comparison on the characters. This is required, otherwise the examples

> A man, a plan, a canal, Panama
>
> Desserts, I stressed

would not be palidromes.

To remove special characters from the user input, you can use lambda

```
string userW; cout << "Enter a sentence: \n"; getline(cin, userW);
userW.erase(remove_if(userW.begin(), userW.end(), [](char c) {return !isalpha(c); }), userW.end());
```

**EDIT**  you can also try the following to avoid the need for lambda:

```
  userW.erase(std::copy_if(userW.begin(), userW.end(), userW.begin(), isalpha), userW.end());
```

to do a case-insensitive comparison, in the function isPal, you can change this:

> if ((myWord[r]) != (myWord[t]))

into this:

```
if (tolower(myWord[r]) != tolower(myWord[t]))
```

Comment: I added what you said to try and delete special characters but I am getting 'remove_if' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @mb13 `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Question, When I run it on cpp.sh it works great, but when I try running it on secure shell, I am getting these errors on the lambda,  **error: expected primary-expression before â[â token
**error: expected primary-expression before â]â token **error: expected primary-expression before âcharâ

Comment: Most likely it's an old compiler that is not compatible with C++11, so it does not understand lambda. @mb13

Comment: Do you happen to know another way to remove special characters?

Comment: You can do a dedicated function in classic C style. Create some char[] buffer; scan the string's characters one by one: copy any alphabetic character (isalpha(c)) into the buffer. Terminate the buffer by zero (dont forget this!). If you want a one-liner, the one I gave you using lambda is the only one that I know about.

Comment: although not sure if lambda is the only problem with your compiler, replace that line with the following, so that no need for Lamba. See my Edit in the answer.

Comment: I got an error saying ** no matching function for call  copy_if

Answer (score 1):

I have reviewed your program. You are trying to out the string in the function pirnt(). Here is the problem ,when you use

```
 cout << "The sentence backwards is: " << userSent.Print();
```

but funtion  Print()  does not have any return type.(because this is void type). Here you should use

```
cout << "The sentence backwards is: " ;
 userSent.Print();
```

and now it works.